# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 VSCode error

Tags: c, undefined, invocation

I am trying to fix the error in the following C program, that I get in the terminal in VSCode ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("just one small step for coders.one giant leap for\n");
    printf("programmers\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the error that I get while compiling in the VSCode terminal:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing the inclues, this code run for me, and if you are doing everything okay it should run for you:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("just one small step for coders.one giant leap for\n");
    printf("programmers\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: otherwise if the problem persiste provide more details about how are you compiling and running the code

Answer (score 0):

Try to put return data type of main function

```
int main(){
```

Maybe this is noy solution but this is the only reason that comes to mind.